# Prove that $\sin(x^2+x)$ is not periodic using $f(x+T) = f(x)$

Tags: solution-verification, periodic-functions

Proof by contradiction:

let $\sin(x^2+x)$ be periodic,
hence,

$$\sin((x+T)^2+x+T) = \sin(x^2+x)$$
$$x^2 + 2xT + T^2 + x + T- x^2 - x = 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$2xT +T^2 + T= 2k\pi$$
$$\frac{2xT +T^2 + T}{2\pi}= k$$
which is impossible, since $x \in \mathbb{R}$,and $T$ is a constant, $2xT +T^2 + T$ can't be a multiple of $2\pi$
Is this proof correct?

Comment: your second equality is wrong a priori.

Comment: $\sin(x+T) = \sin(x), x+T -  x = 2\pi$?

Comment: Beside the other issues, in your second equation you forgot the $x+T$ part. You got just the $(x+T)^2$

Comment: @HengWei: $\sin(x+222\pi)=\sin(x)$ but $x+222\pi-x\neq 2\pi$.

Comment: It should be not $2\pi$  but $2\pi k$ where integer $k$ depends on $x$.

Comment: @Mark then $2xT +T^2 + T$ can't be a multiple of $2\pi$?

Comment: Why not? Take $T=0$.

Comment: ... or $x=0$ and $T$ the positive root of $T^2+T= 25\pi$.

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ is periodic, then so is its derivative $f'$. If $f(x)=\sin(x+x^2)$, then $$f'(x)=(2x+1)\cos(x^2+x),$$
which is continuous and unbounded. Therefore, it's not periodic, and thus $f$ is not periodic.

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to prove it w/o using the notion of derivatives

Comment: This requirement in not in the question. This answer is correct and short and the OP should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea is fine. However, instead of $\alpha-\beta=2\pi$ you'd have to work with something like

> $\alpha-\beta$ is an even  multiple of $\pi$ or $\alpha+\beta$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$

and would run into some technicalities because said multiple may even vary with $x$. It is nevertheless possible to make this work in a rigorous manner.

For example, both $\frac{\alpha-\beta}\pi=\frac{2Tx+T^2+T}\pi$ and $\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}=\frac{2x^2+(2T+2)x+T^2+T}{\pi}$ have an integer value only for countable many values of $x$ (as long as $T\ne0$), so certainly not for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: if $\alpha - \beta$ is an even multiple of $\pi$, then $2xT+T^2+T=2k\pi$

Comment: $2xT +T^2 + T$ can't be a multiple of $2\pi$

Comment: and why is $\alpha + \beta$ an odd multiple of $\pi$? could you please explain